# Flyways commandline for oracle migrations fails when "set serverout on" specified in scrip even with enterprise edition

Tags: flyway

Flyways commandline for oracle migrations fails when "set serverout on" specified in scrip even with enterprise edition

/flyway/flyway-5.2.4/flyway -enterprise -licenseKey=xxxxxxx  -user=system -password=xxxxxx -url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@//xxxxxx:xxx/dbname.example.com -baselineOnMigrate=true -locations=filesystem:/tmp migrate
Flyway Enterprise Edition (trial) 5.2.4 by Boxfuse licensed to Coredigital Media until 2019-04-21
WARNING: You are using a 30 day limited Flyway trial license. After 30 days you must either upgrade to a full Flyway Enterprise Edition license or downgrade to Flyway Community Edition.
Database: jdbc:oracle:thin:@//xxxx:xxxx/dbname.example.com (Oracle 12.1)
Successfully validated 2 migrations (execution time 00:00.217s)
Current version of schema "SYSTEM": 1
Migrating schema "SYSTEM" to version 2 - LRE RESP FNL ROLLOUT DLP
ERROR: Migration of schema "SYSTEM" to version 2 - LRE RESP FNL ROLLOUT DLP failed! Please restore backups and roll back database and code!
ERROR:

### Migration V2__LRE_RESP_FNL_ROLLOUT_DLP.sql failed

SQL State  : 42000
Error Code : 922
Message    : ORA-00922: missing or invalid option
Location   : /tmp/V2__LRE_RESP_FNL_ROLLOUT_DLP.sql (/tmp/V2__LRE_RESP_FNL_ROLLOUT_DLP.sql)
Line       : 1
Statement  : set serveroutput on

Answer (score 0):

Please file an issue in the Flyway issue tracker with the exact steps how to reproduce, including the config used and the SQL file causing the problem.

Comment: Thanks. Can you please share link of flyway issue tracker?

Comment: I am using enterprise trial version edition and in the sql script first line is "set server out on" and it fails.